# JavaScript API for a custom picture map which can work offline and support Markers?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have an image of a city and I want to make a HTML5 application which is like a map,
I want to add my own picture, add Markers, it needs to be zoom-able, and it needs to work offline.

I thought about Google Maps API though it doesnt work offline, Is there a JavaScript API that does?